# Edit formula containing special characters or punctuation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to ask for help to edit my Formula using VBA in cell B4 containing formula :

```
="ER/CRCC-GTGC/PO/ER/CRCC-GTGC/PO/"&C9&","&C13&","&C17&","&C21&","&C24&","&C27&","&C30&","&C33
```

By using a command button when i delete a rows containing any of those cells in the formula, the cell B4 will become #REF! So i am trying to edit the cell formula below

```
="ER/CRCC-GTGC/PO/ER/CRCC-GTGC/PO/"&C9&","&C13&","&C17&","&#REF!&","&#REF!&","&#REF!&","&#REF!&","&#REF!
```

by removing the following characters :

```
&","&#REF!
```

This way the formula is updated without the deleted cell values (#Ref!)

My Code :

```
Sub FixPOReferror()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim bottomC As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range


Worksheets("Summary").Activate

ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = False

bottomC = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng1 In Range("B4:B" & bottomC)

**' MY ERROR IS IN THIS AREA** 
rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, "&", "&#REF!", "")
   
Next rng1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get the right result is to perform two replacements to address all cases.

- If any cell is deleted (except the first one), the string to be replaced (deleted) is this one: **&","&#REF!**
- If the first cell is deleted, the string to be replaced is this one: **&#REF!","**

The VBA Code:

```
' Using the Chr() function
rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, Chr(38) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(38) & "#REF!", "")
rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, "#REF!" & Chr(38) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(38), "")


'Without using the Chr() function
rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, "&"",""&#REF!", "")
rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, "&#REF!&"",""", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rng1.Replace What:=chr(34)&chr(44)&chr(34)&"&#REF!&”, LookAt:=xlPart, Replacement:=””
rng1.Replace What:=chr(34)&chr(44)&chr(34)&”&#REF!”, LookAt:=xlPart, Replacement:=””
```

Instead of:

```
rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, "&", "&#REF!", "")
```

Comment: Not working. 

I need to remove anything that matches this &","&#REF!

they are automatically at the end of the last cell that was declared in the formula

Comment: so right after C57 in the screenshot comes &","&#REF! which gets repeated till the end. So clearing those will correct the formula automatically

Comment: I was able to do the same for P63 with the below code :

rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, "#REF!+", "")
        rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, "+#REF!", "")

Except the code in B4 is for joining cell values along with "," string

Comment: Also need to clear the commas.

Comment: Giving error Compile error syntax error. I need to clear this exactly

&","&#REF!

The problem being that & and " " are parts of code in vba whereas in the Excel formula its just as text.

Comment: So whenever you use "" and & in VBA its taking it as part of VBA Coding, whereas what im looking for is to clear any text that matches &","&#REF! in the cell formula

Comment: Updated. Need to get rid of comma and quotation Mark's as well.

Comment: Still getting Compile Error : Syntax error

Comment: Anything to do with the version im using Microsoft Office 365 ?

Comment: Or I was just thinking. What if we declare something with value (String maybe ?)
&","&#REF! 
and we can use that instead in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I misread how the quotes are used in the original formula. I'll revise.

Comment: Its now saying Compile Error : Argument not optional 

.Replace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241139/discussion-between-bugdrown-and-soldier2gud4me).

Answer (score 0):

Your replace-statement is wrong (wrong order of arguments), have a look to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function)

In VBA, when you need a quote within a string, simply double it.

An ampersand-character *within* a string is not interpreted by VBA, no need to do anything with it.

An advice: If you write formulas using VBA, always write the formula into an intermediate variable so you can check using the debugger if the result is what you expect.

So if you want to replace `&","#REF!` - write `&"",""#REF!` - just double the quotes *within you search term* so that the VBA runtime understands the it didn't reach the end of a string.

```
Dim newFormula As String
newFormula = Replace(rng1.Formula, "&"",""#REF!", "")
Debug.Print newFormula  ' Press 
rng1.Formula = newFormula
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but it didnt work. Theres a missing chr & before #Ref!

Been trying variations and cant get the desired result.

Comment: Error is Runtime error 13 : Type Mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bugdrown i was able to get my result with the below code :

```
rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, Chr(38) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(38) & "#REF!", "")
```

Comment: This works if any cell is deleted except for the first one. To also address the first one being deleted, you will have to add another line: rng1.Formula = Replace(rng1.Formula, "#REF!" & Chr(38) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Chr(38), "")

Comment: Hi @Zivko Kozarov, please post your comment as an answer !!! Youre right, and this is the most appropriate answer. Thank you very much. I shall mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Hi @soldier2gud4me, you're welcome. I will post the detailed answer